# Select rows from a table not matched in another table

Tags: mysql

So I have the following:

A lookup table that has two columns and looks like this for example:

```
userid     moduleid
  4           4
```

I also have a users table that has a primary key `userid` which the lookup table references. The user table has a few users lets say, and looks like this:

```
userid
  1
  2
  3
  4
```

In this example, it show that the user with ID 4 has a match with module ID 4. The others are not matched to any moduleid.

I need a query that gets me data from the users table WHERE the moduleid is not 4. In my application, I know the module but I don't know the user. So the query should return the other userids apart from 4, because 4 is already matched with module ID 4.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: I took the liberty to change the title of your question as it wasn't very descriptive; I hope I managed to reflect your intent as you meant it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql: Select rows from a table that are not in another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767565/mysql-select-rows-from-a-table-that-are-not-in-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand your question correctly. You can use a sub-query to cross-check the data between both tables using the `NOT IN()` function.

The following will select all `userid` records from the `user_tbl` table that do not exist in the `lookup_tbl` table:

```
SELECT `userid` 
FROM `user_tbl`
WHERE `userid` NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(`userid`) FROM `lookup_tbl` WHERE moduleid = 4
)
```

Comment: That does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, one pretty intuitive way (in my opinion) is the use an `in` predicate to exclude the users with moduleid 4 in the lookup table:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM Lookup WHERE ModuleID = 4)
```

There are other ways, with possibly better performance (using a correlated not exists query or a join for instance).

Answer (score 0):

One other option is to use a `LEFT JOIN` so that you can get the values from both tables, even when there is not a match. Then, pick the rows where there is no `userid` value from the lookup table.

```
SELECT u.userid
FROM usersTable u
    LEFT JOIN lookupTable lt ON u.userid = lt.userid
WHERE lt.userid IS NULL
```

Answer (score -3):

Are you looking for a query like this?

select userid from yourtablename where moduleid<>4