# Query for Selecting except values with two column

Tags: php, sql

i have two tables.
First table column
value is 
`1,2,7`.
Second table column
value is `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`.

what i needed is i want to fetch second table values except first table values.Result should be `3,4,5,6,8,9,10`.I do no what is the query for this one.Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql: Select rows from a table that are not in another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767565/mysql-select-rows-from-a-table-that-are-not-in-another)

Comment: You have plenty of options... `EXCEPT`, `NOT IN`, `JOIN ON <>` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT value FROM secondtable WHERE value NOT IN (SELECT value FROM firsttable)
```

Comment: SELECT accname FROM m_costacc WHERE accname NOT IN (SELECT m_AccHeadID FROM m_accounthead_fa) .I used this query but im getting empty result

Comment: NOT IN (SELECT m_AccHeadID as accname FROM m_accounthead_fa)

Comment: Kindly mark the answer that worked for you so that others can benefit from the question as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The standard SQL is to use `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t2.*
from t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.value = t2.value);
```