# MYSQL: check data from other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, how to show data if not exist in tbsale table?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: im just newbie, please help me

Comment: You should not treat SO as a code writing service - you should at least try searching first - a quick google search for _mysql query to find records in one table not in another_ just now came up with this as the top entry : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another & this as second : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767565/mysql-select-rows-from-a-table-that-are-not-in-another You get better response on SO if you show you have put some effort in yourself.

Comment: thanks so much @PaulF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT Employ_Id, Employ_Name
FROM tbemploy
WHERE tbemploy.Employ_Id NOT IN (SELECT Employ_Id FROM tbsale)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXPECT for this in SQL:

```
SELECT EmployeeID,Employee_Name
FROM TBEmployee
EXCEPT
SELECT TBSalary.EmployeeID,Employee_Name
FROM TBSalary
INNER JOIN TBEmployee ON TBEmployee.EmployeeID=TBSalary.EmployeeID
```

Comment: EXCEPT op is using MySQL (if tag is correct) which does not have that operator.