# Sql Join syntax on two tables MySql

Tags: mysql

I use as RDBMS the version 5.5.24-log of MySql.

With this sql query in output I have all records presents on the two tables `tbl_1` and `tbl_2`:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_1` CB
JOIN `tbl_2` A ON A.xCode = CB.xCode
AND RIGHT (A.xElement, 1) = CB.xElement
WHERE
    CB.xType IN ('A')
AND MONTH(xDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 4
ORDER BY xDate DESC;
```

Now I need extract from `tbl_1` **all records not presents** in `tbl_2` and I have tried this sql query but I have error

> Lost connection to MySQL server during query

```
SELECT i.* FROM
    `tbl_1` i
LEFT JOIN `tbl_2` o ON o.xCode = i.xCode_cabina
AND RIGHT (o.xElement, 1) = i.xElement
WHERE
    i.xType IN ('A')
AND MONTH(xDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 4
AND o.xElement IS NULL ;
```

Can you please help me figure out the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you having internet connectivity issues?

Comment: Consider using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` instead of a join.

Answer (score 0):

Select i.* From `tbl_1` i
WHERE i.xType in ('A') and 
MONTH(i.xDate) bewteen 1 and 4 and 
i.xCode_cabina not exist (select o.xCode from `tbl_2` o where o.xElement is null);

Comment: thanks but in your syntax [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS (

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_1 
WHERE xCode NOT IN (SELECT xCode FROM tbl_2)
```

Source: [Mysql: Select rows from a table that are not in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767565/mysql-select-rows-from-a-table-that-are-not-in-another)

Comment: Thank you, but in my case I need also check the column **xElement** over that the column **xCode**