# mysql select from table 1 where no match in table 2

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, both contain email address.
I need to return all rows in table 1 that do not have a matching email address in table 2.
For simplicity sake we can just say they both have two fields, name and email.

Comment: isaace answered ... waiting for timer to expire to check the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from table1 where emailAddress not it (select email address from table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try LEFT JOIN with NULL in where clause. In LEFT JOIN, if table2 has no matching values, it will be represented by NULL.

> SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.email = Table2.email WHERE Table2.email IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
table_A.column_1, 
table_A.column_2, 
table_A.email

FROM table_A

WHERE table_A.email 
NOT IN ( SELECT table_B.email FROM table_B )
```

An example with several columns from Table A.

Both, Table A and Table B have a column named "email".

Matching emails from Table B will be omitted in the query results.

( This question is similar to [Mysql: Select rows from a table that are not in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767565/mysql-select-rows-from-a-table-that-are-not-in-another) )