# How to choose values from A table which are absent in B table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in mySQL DB: A & B.

a, b, c columns.

Table A:

```
 a(1) = 1 
 a(2) = 2
 a(3) = 3
```

Table B:

```
 a(1) = 1 
 a(2) = 2
```

So, we could see that in B table there is no row with a = 3. How could I request DB to find it?

So response (one row) could looks like:

```
a(1) = 3 
b(1) =..
c(1) =..
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql: Select rows from a table that are not in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767565/mysql-select-rows-from-a-table-that-are-not-in-another)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option uses `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.a
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE b.a = a.a);
```

Another option would be to do an anti-join:

```
SELECT a.a
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
    ON a.a = b.a
WHERE b.a IS NULL;
```

Comment: Yes, sure. Just need to wait for 7 minutes before it allows to mark it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also give up joins and use WHERE and nested SELECT: 
suppose TabA holds values of 1,2,3 in  subsequent rows of column ValA
and TabB holds values  of 1,2 in subsequent rows of column ValB
and you want only a  row containing value of 3 from TabA
you can do this without joins:

```
SELECT  Val_A
FROM TabA  
WHERE Val_A NOT IN (SELECT Val_B FROM TabB)
```

Comment: Excellent, Appreciate your support!