# How to find a value that does not exist in a (one) table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have 2 tables, `app` and `app_log`.

In `app` table :

```
id   app_id    app_name
1     1234      aaa
2     2334      bbb
3     9374      ccc
```

In table `app_log` :

```
id   app_id    app_name    app_status_id
1     1234      aaa            NULL
1     1234      aaa            1
1     1234      aaa            2
1     1234      aaa            4
1     1234      aaa            5
2     2334      bbb            1
2     2334      bbb            2
2     2334      bbb            3
2     2334      bbb            4
2     2334      bbb            5
3     9374      ccc            1
3     9374      ccc            2
3     9374      ccc            4
3     9374      ccc            5
```

How do I find an app id and app name where the `app_status_id` does not have any status id of `3`?

I tried below query but it doesn't show any result although there are `app_id` that don't have any `app_status_id` of `3`.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    app.app_id,
    app.app_name
    FROM
    app,
    app_log
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM app_log WHERE app_status_id=2)
```

Please kindly help me.

Expected result / result that I want:

```
app_id    app_name
1234        aaa
9374        ccc
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Sample data is great, you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Remove `app_log` from FROM clause. Also remove DISTINCT, it is excess.

Comment: See the following answer to the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11767601/5389997

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Neither your sample data nor your description tell us if apps should be selected that don't exist at all in the table app_log.